# XSTL 2.0 sub-total and total-sum given multiple rows

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am currently learning some XSTL 2.0. I am looking to convert XML documents to neatly formatted HTML files.

What I am currently trying to do is:

```
Group Suppliers, [sort them A-Z]
List their Items [sort them 1-n]
Calculate the QTY * Cost
Sum the cost of all orders from that supplier
Sum the total cost of all suppliers
```

The output should look like:

```
Supplier A
Item #  Qty Item Price  Total
1       5   5.50        27.50
3       10  5.50        55.00
Sub-total   $82.50
Supplier B
Item #  Qty Item Price  Total
2       10  10          100.00
Sub-total   $100.00
Total-cost  $182.50
```

I can get all the sorting and grouping etc to work as intended, but I cannot work out how to calculate the Sub-total, or the Total-cost values, because they are calculated and not part of the original XML document. Do I some-how store the calculated cost so that I can SUM it after it has completed the group,sort,calculate function?

Here is my current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Orders>
    <Order OrderNo="1">
        <Supplier>Supplier A</Supplier>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        <Price>5.50</Price>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderNo="2">
        <Supplier>Supplier B</Supplier>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        <Price>10</Price>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderNo="3">
        <Supplier>Supplier A</Supplier>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        <Price>5.50</Price>
    </Order
```

Here is the current XSL 2.0 file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>
                </p>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="Orders/Order"
                    group-by="Supplier">
                    <xsl:sort select="Supplier" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()"
                        group-by="@OrderNo">
                        <xsl:sort select="@OrderNo" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Supplier" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Item #</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>Item Price</td>
                            <td>Total</td>
                        </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:sort select="@OrderNo" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@OrderNo" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Quantity" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Quantity * Price,'0.00')" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="Sub-total" colspan="3">Sub-total</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the resulting HTML output:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p></p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Supplier A</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item #</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Item Price</td>
            <td>Total</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5.50</td>
            <td>27.50</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>5.50</td>
            <td>55.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="Sub-total" colspan="3">Sub-total</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Supplier B</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item #</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Item Price</td>
            <td>Total</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>100.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="Sub-total" colspan="3">Sub-total</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the lengthy read! Just need to crack the sum part(s).

Kind Regards

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/(Quantity * Price)),'0.00')" />
```

to get the subtotal of the current group of `Order`s.

Comment: Very nice calculation method along with current-group(), plus one.

Comment: Oh, I think I was over complicating it highly! Thanks for the quick response and accurate solution! Is it also possible (using my XLST) to calculate the over-all, e.g. Total cost of all suppliers? i.e. Supplier A total + Supplier B total? Do I make a SUM(current-group()) outside the for-each loop?

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you @michael.hor257k (new to stack)

Comment: To get the grand total, use: `xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/Orders/Order/(Quantity * Price)),'0.00')" />`. This uses an absolute path, so it will work from anywhere - though properly it should be used outside of any `xsl:for-each-group` (and consequently, outside of any `table`).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple and apply sum on the current group of Order nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>
                </p>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="Orders/Order" group-by="Supplier">
                    <xsl:sort select="Supplier" data-type="text" order="ascending" />

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Supplier" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Item #</td>
                            <td>Qty</td>
                            <td>Item Price</td>
                            <td>Total</td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:sort select="@OrderNo" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@OrderNo" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Quantity" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Quantity*Price,'0.00')" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="Sub-total" colspan="3">Sub-total</td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/(Quantity*Price)),'0.00')"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @michael.hor257k Apologies. I did not notice that an answer had been posted as I was editing the OP's XSLT.